# jQuery selector :not(:animated)

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're trying to make sure our JavaScript menu, which loads content, doesn't get overrun with commands before the content in question loads and is unfurled via .show('blind', 500), because then the animations run many times over, and it doesn't look so great. So I've got about six selectors that look like this:

```
("#center_content:not(:animated)")
```

And it doesn't seem to be having any effect. Trying only :animated has the expected effect (it never works, because it doesn't start animated), and trying :not(div) also has this effect (because #center_content is a div). For some reason, :not(:animated) seems not to be changing the results, because even when I trigger the selector while the div in question is visibly animated, the code runs. I know I've had success with this sort of thing before, but the difference here eludes me.

---

```
$("#center_content:not(:animated)").hide("blind", 500, function () {
    var selector_str = 'button[value="' + url + '"]';
    //alert(selector_str);
    var button = $(selector_str);
    //inspectProperties(button);
    $("#center_content:not(:animated)").load(url, CenterContentCallback);
    if (button) {
        $("#navigation .active").removeClass("active");
        button.addClass("active");
        LoadSubNav(button);
    }
});
```

I hope this provides sufficient context. I feel like the second selector is overkill (since it would only be run if the first selector succeeded), but I don't see how that would cause it to behave in this way.

---

Here's the snippet that seemed to be working in the other context:

```
function clearMenus(callback) {
        $('[id$="_wrapper"]:visible:not(:animated)').hide("blind", 500, function() {
           $('[id^="edit_"]:visible:not(:animated)').hide("slide", 200, function() {
            callback();
            });
        });
}
```

Here, the animations queue instead of interrupt each other, but it occurs to me that the selector still doesn't seem to be working - the animations and associated loading events *shouldn't be running at all*, because the selectors should fail. While the queueing is nice behavior for animations to display, it made me realize that I seem to have never gotten this selector to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the some part of your js used in the page?

Comment: so you're having problems with multiple animations going off at once for the same element?

Comment: Just in case it's a sizzle limitation, did you try `$("#center_content").not(":animated")`?

Comment: Also, your `if (button)` conditional statement might not do what you think it does: empty jQuery objects still evaluate as `true`. You probably want `if (button.length)` instead.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I was trying .not as well, but long enough ago in the cycle that it might be worth revisiting. I'll try again. Also, you're entirely right about the if (button) statement. Evidently its functionality is not critical, because we never noticed it not working.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's helpful to use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and stop the current animation before you start the new animation.

```js
$("#center_content").stop().hide("blind", 500, function () {});
```

Really depends on how it behaves within your environment. Remember that `.stop()` will stop the animation as it was (eg. halfway through hiding or fading)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand it correctly, but if you want to make sure the user doesn't trigger the menu animation again while it's currently animating(causing it to queue animations and look retarded, this works and should help. I use an `if-statement`. And before any mouseover/off animation I add `.stop(false, true)`.

```
    $('whatever').click(function(){
       //if center_content is not currently animated, do this:
       if ($("#center_content").not(":animated")) {
         $(this).hide(etc. etc. etc.)
       }
       //else if center_content IS currently animated, do nothing.
       else {
         return false;}
    });
```

---

**another example i found elsewhere:**

```
if($("#someElement").is(":animated")) {
    ...
}

if($("#someElement:animated").length) {
    ...
}

// etc
```

then you can do:

```
$("#showBtn").attr("disabled", $("#someElement").is(":animated"));
```